# Constructor Calls Overridable Method (delayed call)

Tags: java, constructor, callback, overriding

I understand this warning in the normal case like:

```
class Test {
  public Test() {
    hello();
  }
  public void hello() {}
}
```

but what if we have something like:

```
class Test {
  public Test() { 
    // Put the call on a queue that will be executed later
    queue.submit( new Runnable() { 
      public void run() {
        hello();
      }
    });
  }
  public void hello() {}
}
```

where the call to hello() will not happen immediately. Is this still bad/risky even in the case where the callback executes long after the subclass is ready constructed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this still bad/risky even in the case where the callback executes long after the subclass is ready constructed

Yes, its still risky. Constructor invocation is *not* atomic, so deferring the invocation of an instance method from the constructor is no less safe if you do it in another thread, since you have no guarantee that the object will be fully constructed when the thread is (eventually) invoked.

Now, ***hypothetically***, if the subclass object is fully constructed (emphasis on if), then yes, the future callback will be safe. In other words, its not passing around the partially constructed object that is dangerous so much as its accessing it.

Comment: In my question I do state "even in the case where the callback executes long after the subclass is ready constructed" though. For example even if I do: Test t = new Test(); queue.start() ( imagining start() here starts up the handling thread ). So basically I wonder if it's still risky in the case where I am totally sure that that the subclass has finished constructing ? (or is that not guaranteed even if the second thread starts up after object is constructed ? )

Comment: @Zitrax - but you are making assumptions that can not be enforced in your code, aka that some constraint elsewhere is going to slow task executions down enough to the point where you won't run into problems. You are also making assumptions about the internal implementation of the queue (aka, that it won't try and access the supplied task in an unsafe manner). Thats way too many assumptions imo, its much safer to fully construct the object, then call another method that will cause its task to be enqueued.

Comment: My example was not good as it involved assumptions, but my question was really that assuming that the the subclass object is fully constructed at the time the callback is invoked - is it then safe ? Or in other words is the "is the object fully constructed" the only problem with calling overridden methods from the constructor or are there other sides of it ?

Comment: @Zitrax - if the subclass object is fully constructed (emphasis on if), then yes, the future callback will be safe. In other words, its not passing around the partially constructed object that is dangerous so much as its *accessing* it.

Comment: Thanks - could you update your answer with that and I can mark it (as I can't mark a comment as the answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes it is risky just because you are exposing the `Test` object to a second thread before it is fully constructed.

If you need to control the initialization of `Test` instances by insuring `hello` is called, consider using a factory method for instantiation.  Combine that with a private constructor and you can guarantee `hello` is safely called on all `Test` objects:

```
public Test {
    /**
     * Factory method to create Test instances and safely call public method
     */
    public static Test getInstance() {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.hello();
        return test;
    }

    /**
     * Private constructor to control Test object creation.
     */
    private Test() {
      super();
    }

    public void hello() {
    }
}
```